# Xcode 7 fails build with a segfault 11 error with Swift 2.1 inheritance pattern

Tags: xcode, swift, inheritance, xcode7, swift2

When I use the following inheritance pattern, XCode has problems and throws the error `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11`

```
protocol IDable {
    var id: String { get }
}

class Mappable<T: IDable>: IDable {

    let id: String;

    init(id: String) {
        self.id = id;
    }
}

class Test: Mappable<Test> {

}
```

This is not good. It seems like this code should compile, and all I can think of is that there's a bug in XCode.

Has anyone else run into this problem and found a workaround?